# Systemjs can't find ng2-dv3.component

Tags: angular, d3.js, systemjs

I have configured in my `systemjs.config.js` file by adding `'ng2-nvd3': 'npm:ng2-nvd3/build/index.js'`,

Then, I added the import import of `NvD3Component` in my module as stated by https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3 documentation, 
And finally I added `import {NvD3Component} from 'ng2-nvd3'` to my imports and  I added it to my declarations as `declarations: [NvD3Component]`.

Here is the XHR error:

```
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/build/ng2-nvd3.component
```

Angular v4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

solutions steps: 
**1)**
edit the systemjs.config.js file from

```
'ng2-nvd3': 'npm:ng2-nvd3/build/index.js'
```

to

```
'ng2-nvd3': 'npm:ng2-nvd3/build/ng2-nvd3.component.js'
```

**2)** make sure your not using **d3 version 4** as it's not yet supported by **nvd3**